# Make anchor tags behave like checkboxes and radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list like:

```
  <ul class="list-one">
    <li><a href="#">Hip Hop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Country</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pop</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Religious</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I want the anchors to behave like checkboxes. I have another similar list and I want the checkboxes there to behave like radio buttons.

Is there any way to do this using jquery? I searched google but couldnt really find anything.

Comment: Why not make checkboxes and radio button act like anchors?  That's a lot easier.

Comment: Yes you can do that. But at least try something and show it here. Than we can guide you.#

Comment: Also what exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "behave like checkboxes"? Do you want to toggle the colour (or otherwise visually indicate some sort of on/off state) when the links are clicked?

Comment: Why would u want to switch the behaviour from checkboxes <--> radiobuttons ?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after, but `selectable` in JqueryUI might be a start. http://jqueryui.com/selectable/#serialize

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why _can't_ you use checkboxes and radio buttons? I'm just trying to understand why you need to _fake_ something when the browser provides perfectly fine tags for this...

Comment: @DarkBee - Not sure what the OP is trying to do, but to me "checkboxes to behave like radio buttons" would make sense when the user is supposed to select one or none from several options - which is a problem with _real_ radio buttons because once one is checked the user can change the selection but not remove it.

Comment: I dont want the boxes in checkboxes. According to the design, the anchor text should behave like checkboxes... hope that makes sense

Comment: @AlexZahir "behave like checkboxes" is very vague.  Do you want a check mark to appear?  Do you want to toggle something on the page? Do you still want to link to another page?  If you don't know ask who ever wrote the design for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

You can work with the jQuerys `parent()` and `siblings()` methods.

check this [jsFiddle Demo for radios](http://jsfiddle.net/zvhzx/1/)!

**jQuery Radio:**

```
$(".list-one a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
});
```

**jQuery Checkboxes**:

```
$(".list-one a").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected'); 
});
```

If you need the radios for a form, you can use `label` instead of the `a` tag and hide the radios with css.

check this [jsFiddle Demo for radios](http://jsfiddle.net/cJJ44/)!

**HTML Radios:**

```
<ul class="list-one">
  <li>
    <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="list" value="Hip Hop" />
    <label for="input-1">Hip Hop</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="list" value="Country" />
    <label for="input-2">Country</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="input-3" type="radio" name="list" value="Pop" />
    <label for="input-3">Pop</label>
  </li>
  <li class="selected">
    <input id="input-4" type="radio" name="list" value="Pop" />
    <label for="input-4">Religious</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Don't forget to change the `type` attribute to `checkbox` for checkboxes.

**jQuery Radios**:

```
$(".list-one label").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected"); 
});
```

**jQuery Checkboxes**:

```
$(".list-one label").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected'); 
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.list-one label { cursor: pointer; }
.list-one input { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

For checkboxes, simply:

```
$(".list-one > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

Or using delegation:

```
$(".list-one").on("click", "> li > a", function() {
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

For radio buttons, you add rather than toggling and remove the class from siblings:

```
$(".list-one > li > a").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

Or using delegation:

```
$(".list-one").on("click", "> li > a", function() {
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

More to explore:

- [`$` / `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)
- [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on)
- [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)
- [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)
- [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)
- [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)
- [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass)

---

That said, using *real* checkboxes and radio buttons is frequently the better way to go, not least for support of mobile devices (tablets, phones, etc.). You can use `label` elements to make them easy to click, and style them thoroughly, but by making them *real* checkboxes / radio buttons, you give the user agent (browser) information to work with that you're losing by rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

checkbox's were designed to be used in that fashion and radio buttons in the latter, whey would you want to replace with anchors? if you want to theme your elements there are jQuery plugins that can replace the actual checkboxes and radio buttons with prettyfied versions see here http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-transform/

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<ul class="list-one">
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="music" value="HipHop">Hip hop</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Country">Country=</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Pop">Pop</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="music" value="Religious">Religious</li>
  </ul>
```